# iPad best practice to keep backend data model

Tags: database, ipad, plist, sqlite

I am developing iPad application,

- A set of forms that user has to fill (roughly 500 text fields).
- The form fields are displayed in a UITable view.
- Once user fill the forms he/she can uploaded the data to the server.
- Until its uploaded, the data should be persist in a temporary location in the local disk.

In my application design, I am using NSMutableDictionery, which is always being updated when the user updating the forms.

What is the best way to keep save NSMutableDictionery in the local disk. 
SQL Lite or PList ?

/chatcja

Answer (score 3):

If you are only ever saving one form at a time, a plist would be fine. If you would ever have the need to store multiple instances of the form and need to find them based on user-generated contents, using a more sophisticated storage mechanism like SQLite or CoreData would probably be more appropriate.